# Create autocmd for downloaded files (filename contains spaces and incrementing numbers)?

Tags: autocmd

I want an autocmd for downloaded log files. These files are called `log.txt` or `log (1).txt` (where `1` could be any number). (On Firefox/Windows, when you download a file with the same name as another file, it adds a number to separate.)

So far I've figured out three things that tripped me up:

- `setfiletype` doesn't work if something else (like vim's ftdetect) already set a filetype.
- I need to escape spaces.
- `*` works very differently from other vim regex (`:help {aupat}`)

I have this, but it seems very awkward:

```
au BufRead log[\ ()0-9]\\\{0,10\}.txt  set filetype=log
```

Comment: Could you tell us more what do you dislike in your solution? Does it match the files you want? Does it match too much?

Answer (score 1):

> setfiletype doesn't work if something else (like vim's ftdetect) already set a filetype

That's the whole purpose of this command and is documented on the relevant help page. When multiple patterns match only the first one will matter. Use `:set` command otherwise.

> it seems very awkward

You don't have to match in `aupat` strictly. For example,

```
autocmd BufRead *.txt
    \    if expand("<afile>") =~? 'log...'
    \ |      set ft=log
    \ |  endif
```

Or you can even move that whole mess into separate function.